# Copy file to application directory

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have trouble getting it to copy file from src to destination.

```
var asMsg_path:String = fileRef.nativePath;
var origFileLoc:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath(asMsg_path);
var newFileLoc:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("/java/"+asMsg);
```

launch an AIR app in debug mode. I need to copy a file from asMsg to the Java folder in the same location as the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
origFileLoc.moveTo(newLocation:FileReference, overwrite:Boolean);
```